# Box not found. Did you forget to call Hive.openBox()? - does not detect the box even though I have opened it

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I am trying to open my box after getting some data on a particular page and moving to another page. However, it keeps saying that I did not open it. Why?

```
GestureDetector(
   onTap: () async{
   final data = Hive.openBox('${setTask.getAt(index)}');
       setState(() {
       Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>                                          
              Tasks(setTask.getAt(index), data)));
          }
       );
    },
);
```

The next page

```
final opendata;

  Tasks(@required this.opendata);
```

Also..I added a line in my Stateful Widget when the widget builds

> final openBox = Hive.openBox('${widget.hiveName}');

Putting it in initState(){} and using async and await did not work either.

Comment: Where exactly is the error thrown that the box is not open?

Comment: In the next page, in the ListView.builder

Comment: Can you show us the code for that? Currently, we can only say that an `await` is missing, but according to you, this is not the cause.

Comment: Please carefully read what [hive] tag is used for. Correct tag is flutter-hive.

Answer (score 0):

To fix you issue, you have to add **await**, i.e,

```
final data = await Hive.openBox('box');
```

instead of,

```
final data = Hive.openBox('box');
```

The problem here is, Flutter is rebuilding the state without waiting for Hive to actually open the box, and hence the error. Adding an **await** would tell Flutter to keep track of Hive opening the box and work accordingly (i.e, refresh state or whatever you want to do).

Comment: If I need to use **await**, I will also have to use **async** but how can I use **async** for a stateful widget.                                                                                                                                      I had tried this but it did not work